# On a METAR, what does DSPTD mean?

Tags: weather, metar

KDEN is currently reporting the following METAR:

```
SPECI KDEN 090325Z 34031G37KT 10SM -PLRA FEW015 OVC036 08/03 A2992 RMK AO2 PK WND 35037/0325 RAB04PLB25 TS DSPTD P0000 T00830028 $
```

I have no idea what `DSPTD` stands for. My best guess is "dissipated". I have been unable to find anything online, can someone help confirm this?

Comment: That is what it means, but it should be taken with the TS too: `TS DSPTD`, I can't find any official source for the code though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a METAR with the addition of U.S. Observations, and according to the [details of the abbreviations used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR#U.S._METAR_abbreviations) there is no such value as DSPTD.

I suspect you are right, that it *should* have been DSIPTG - which does indeed mean "dissipating". The full decode of the Remarks section of your example METAR is as follows

- A02 - automated station with precipitation descriminator.
- PK WND 35037/0325 - Peak wind 350 degrees at 37 knots between 03 and 25mins
- RAB04 - Rain began at 04mins (You can infer the hour from the main report)
- PLB25 - Ice pellets began at 25mins (Again, inferring the hour from the report)
- TS DSPTD - Thunderstorms which dissipated
- P0000 - Trace amount of  hourly precipitation

I should add that I'm by no means an expert at decoding this part of a METAR, I made judicious use of [this page](http://www.met.tamu.edu/class/metar/quick-metar.html).